# Can not receive additional parameter using NextAuth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth in my NextJS 13 app. Initially, when the user is authenticated, session returns three parameters: `name`, `email` and `picture`. My goal is to add an additional parameter `progress` that will be updated during the user's work.

As I keep the registered user in MongoDB I use NextJS Api Route to update the user and add `progress` parameter by PUT request. But the problem is despite that additional parameter was added, the session keeps returning the same three parameters: `name`, `email` and `picture` without `progress`.

The question is how to force the session to return additional parameter?

PS. At the same time I'm not sure that I'm doing it right by trying to add additional parameter via API instead of NextAuth itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the session object for NextAuth you have to modify the session callback like so:

```
async session({ session, user }) {
    if (session.user) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
      session.user.progress = user.progress;
    }
    return session;
  },
```

After extending the object, you need to extend the types aswell.

Like so:

```
import type { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user?: {
      id: string;
      progress: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
  interface DefaultUser {
    progress: string;
  }
}
```

More info: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks

Comment: The second part of this does not look to be included in the linked documentation. Can you explain why extending the types would persist the progress field in the session?

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I am using Oauth and jwt in NextAuth. I had to also use the jwt to pass the new variables to the session callback:

```
callbacks: {
  async jwt({ session, user }) {
  // check if oauth account exists, indicating first sign in
    if (account) {
      // your api call for additional information from db
      response = ...

      token.progress = response.progress;
    }

    // continue to return token before the session callback runs
    return token;
  },
  async session({ session, token }) {
    if (token) {
      session.error = token.error;
      session.user.progress = token.progress;
    }
    return session;
}
```